# String Literal Concatenation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, c, database

To form string literals in **c** that take up more than one line, you can concatenate the two strings by a backslash, then press the RETURN key. The backslash causes the compiler to ignore the following newline character. For example, the string literal:

```
"Long strings can be bro\
ken into two or more pieces."
```

Or a useful case in c for define a C preprocessor:

```
#define DISP_TEST \
{\
    int l_id = 1;\
    PubDisplayGen(3,_txtOTHERS_(l_id,SID_PRINTING));\
    PubUpdateWindow();\
}
```

Is there anything equal to this for **mysql**

For example when run these commands

```
SET @test = "select * 
from test4";

Select @test;
```

The output is

[image]

While desired output is :

[image]

Don't forget the usecase of this demand. I wanna to know is it possible? Or is there any equal character in the SQL?

Comment: You can do dynamic sql in a stored procedure, tons of information available on that.

Comment: Gordon managed to find a way to do this, but what I would suggest since you are using C, is to just use statements from C to insert your data.  Then, you may concatenate C strings and take advantage of any multiline options is already has.

Answer (score 6):

Although I don't really recommend using it, MySQL will automatically concatenate two adjacent strings.  So this does what you want:

```
SET @test = 'select * '
'from test4';

Select @test;
```

I don't recommend this because it looks like a syntax error.  And a small change  could significantly change the meaning.